# Google Datastore overusing entity "kinds"

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to overuse entity "kinds" (say there are 100, 000 for a given namespace) ?

Example scenario:

Using **kinds** to group "user_email" and the entity **id** as "post_id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have each user's email as a kind, then have each entity be a post linked to that email.

While the system would not stop you from doing that (there is no limit, as far as I know, to the number of kinds you can create), this is DEFINITELY not following best practices.

Why not have a parent kind "email", containing the email and a bunch of information about your user, and a kind "post", that has post ID, post description, whatever, with a PARENT that would have to be an "email"?

To have more information on ancestor relationships, look at [the following article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths).

Comment: you understood correctly and i agree with your answer/recommendation. The reason for my question was the nodejs (gcloud) library makes is very convenient to use **kind** as a preset filter. Indeed, as you mentioned, this was not google's intended use for **kinds**.